# newbie question: how to show a drop down menu with this function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My model object (e.g. MyObject) has one property (e.g. color), the "color" property holds a string value which comes from a list of string (e.g. `colors=['red','yellow', 'black']`).

now, I have one instance of myObject get from database and show on the view page in a row, I need to show the 'color' property of myObject in a drop down menu with the current value as the default selected. How to implement this in Rails 3 in my view page.

(Later, when user select from the dropdown menu, the object will be updated in DB based on user's selection)

Please explain with instance "myObject" and list "colors=[...]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example in haml:

```
%select{:name => 'color'}
  %option{:value=> @my_object.color}
    = @my_object.color
  -Color::COLORS.each do |c|
    %option{:value=>c.name}
      =h c.name
```

Assuming you have a constant list in the Color model class called COLORS, and that you have instantiated @my_object from the action that invoked this view.

Example in html.erb (a little rusty on this...):

```
<select name="color">
    <option value="<%= @my_object.color %>">
        <%= @my_object.color %>
    </option>
    <% Color::COLORS.each do |c| %>
        <option value="<%= c.name %>">
            <%=h c.name %>
        <option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, I followed your code and got this error message "Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal." which complain about line 16 as follows 15:     select(:name=>"color")
16:       %option{:value=>"myObject.color"}
17:         =myObject.color

Comment: It works, in haml, before select tag should be a percentage sign, this course the error. Anyhow, Thanks!

Comment: I was just about to reply with that, sorry about the confusion , glad it worked :D

Comment: better to use helpers like `select`, `form_for` etc (for erb, of course)

Comment: I agree, it's better to go with convention. Personally in the past I've had some trouble properly using the form tag helpers, hence why I did it this way.

Comment: So...anybod can provide the convention solution in rails 3? By the way,Zkoh's solution has one little bug, which is there is a duplicated option with the myObject current color, since current color is showed as default value and the rest options are the full list of COLORS which again contain the current used color.

Comment: so you can remove first option and replace `<option value="<%= c.name %>"><%=h c.name %><option>` with `<option value="<%= c.name %>" <%= "selected" if c.name == c><%=h c.name %><option>`

Comment: or use rails helpers: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select it is prefered

Comment: I tried to use select helper, but I got empty options, because the help needs color.id, color.name, while in my case, my COLORS list holds strings, which means each color has no id neither name. So, I need an example how to use helper in rails 3 for my case??

Comment: To Zkoh, there is a serious problem with your solution. After press the save button, the color selected from options are not updated in DB, I found the myObject passed to my controller always hold the default value or color no matter which color you selected from the drop down menu.

Comment: Mellon, I think I used this code with an AJAX {:onchange => remote_function(...) } call. On second/third thoughts, I think you should go with fl00r's suggestion instead, and use the form helpers. A good place to check is also http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: I used the form helper like: select("my_object", "color", your_color_collection, { :include_blank => true }), but my controller still can only get the default value instead of the selected one, why??

Comment: Would you mind posting your update/create method from your controller?

Answer (score 1):

```
# controller (app/controllers/my_objects_controller.rb):
def edit
  @my_object = MyObject.find params[:id]
end
# view (app/views/my_objects/edit.html.erb):
<% form_for @my_object do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :color, MyObject.colors %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You load the object like this:

```
@my_object = MyObject.find(params[:id], :include => :colors)
```

Then in the view, you can use the select form helper to display the drop-down list like this:

```
<%= f.select :color, @my_object.colors {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, :selected => @my_object.color %>
```

This probably is shown in the edit form and you don't need to do anything special in the update action of the controller other than:

```
def update
  @my_object = MyObject.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @my_object.update_attributes(params[:my_object])
      format.html { redirect_to(@my_object) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @my_object.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What about the colors is a list of string, which does not contain  [c.name, c.id]?? I tried your select tag, but it shows me empty options, I guess it may be because I have no .name .id property for my color. because my color is a string.

Answer (score 0):

I used the form helper in this way:

`select("my_object", "color", your_color_collection, { :include_blank => false })`,

BUT, when I press save button, my controller still can only get the default color value instead of the selected one, why??

I use `button_to("save", myobject_path(myobject), :method=>:put)` which will pass the object to my controller.

in side my controller, update method:

```
class MyobjectsController < ApplicationController
...
def update

     @myobject = myobject.find(params[:id])

     if @myobject.update_attributes(params[:myobject])
      puts @myobject.color #always get default value
      redirect_to myobject_path
    else
      redirect_to myobject_path
    end
  end
...
end
```

Anybody can explain me why I always get default color value instead of the selected one?